# A random space being inserted to a UUID for a email link

Tags: python, html, django, email, uuid

For whatever reason, a random space is getting inserted in the UUID of a record. I send out emails for people to click on confirm or cancel links to update the records in my database. I use the UUID to make sure they are updating the correct record.

I generate the HTML for the link within my forms.py- If I only have the cancel_donation_link in there, it works fine. Once confirmation link is added. It add a space inbetween the canceled link UUID.

```
for special_word in values['special_words']:                     
    print special_word                                           
    text = values['text']                                        
    print text                                                   
    uuid = rescheduled_donor.uuid                                

    if special_word == "confirm_donation_link":                  
        values['text'] = text.replace(                           
            special_word,                                        
            '<a href="http://{0}/actions/email_blasts/confirm/' \
            '{1}">Confirm Donation</a>'.format(                  
                domain,                                          
                uuid                                             
            )                                                    
        )                                                        
        values['special_words'].remove(special_word)             
        continue                                                 

     if special_word == "cancel_donation_link":                  
         values['text'] = text.replace(                          
             special_word,                                       
             '<a href="http://{0}/actions/email_blasts/cancel/' \
             '{1}">Cancel</a>'.format(                           
                 domain,                                         
                 uuid                                            
             )                                                   
         )                                                       
         values['special_words'].remove(special_word)    
         continue
```

Right before I send off all the context to the email template I print out the html which shows NO space in between the UUID

```
<div>If you wish to cancel your donation click here:&nbsp; <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/actions/ema
il_blasts/cancel/f42f1915-2e6b-401c-bd0f-e99ba54e9ea5">Cancel</a>  </div>
```

Once the email is sent, the URL has a space in the UUID section. It gets replaced by %20.
    Cancel

template

```
 <div style="color:#500050">                                            
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}images/email_logo2.jpg">                   
    <p>                                                                 
        {{ message|safe }}                                              
    </p>                                                                

    <p>                                                                 
        {% for image in pages %}                                        
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image }}">                      
        {% endfor %}                                                    
    </p>                                                                

    <p>                                                                 
        {{ closing_message|safe }}                                      

    </p>                                                                
 </div>
```

~

I have no idea why or how this random space is getting inserted.

HTML From Email

```
<div style="color:#500050">

        </p><div>If you have any questions or need any assistance you may reply by e-mail or call &nbsp;customer service <a href="tel:631-234-0000" value="+16312340000" target="_blank">631-234-0000</a>.<br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>To confirm this new date, click here:&nbsp; <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/actions/email_blasts/confirm/1544ce69-3c44-4554-839a-a2fd09f049e3" target="_blank">Confirm Donation</a>  </div><div><br></div><div>To pick a different date, click here:&nbsp; <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/external/1544ce69-3c44-4554-839a-a2fd09f049e3/" target="_blank">Donate</a> </div><div><br></div><div>To cancel your donation, click here:&nbsp; <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/actions/email_blasts/cancel/1544ce%2069-3c44-4554-839a-a2fd09f049e3" target="_blank">Cancel</a> <br></div>
    <p></p>

    <p>

    </p>

    <p>
        <br>

    </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual HTML for that link, as received with the email message? A copy from the raw message content would be best.

Comment: Added the HTML from the email. Don't get how a space could be added to the UUID. If I flip the order and show the canceled link before the confirmation link, both links work just fine. I need the cancel link to be last however.

Comment: I don't know if it would really be the cause but on line 23 of first bit of code you have an extra space before '{1}">Cancel< unlike the others.. (infact the whole function has an extra space) I don't know if that would cause such a weird error but plausible? I'd test it but I don't have a python environment set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the string part of my URL to use the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) function instead of hard coding it. I also noticed a difference from when I had it running locally on my laptop compared to on my staging site on my webfaction server.

```
if special_word == "cancel_donation_link":                              

    values['text'] = text.replace(                           
        special_word,                                        
        '<a href="{0}{1}">Cancel</a>'.format(                
            domain,                                          
            reverse('email_blasts_cancel', kwargs={'donor_uuid': uuid})
        )                                                    
    )
```